# Export detailed reports from Rips Vulnerability Scanner 0.55

Tags: php, vulnerability-scanners

I am using [RIPS](http://rips-scanner.sourceforge.net/) 0.55 to scan for static source code vulnerabilities.

Currently when running it at the directory level it just gives the category and the list of files. Is there a way to extract which line of code the exact vulnerability is.

Currently only way to find that out is through running 1 file at a time which is unpractical for a huge site.

Comment: Which version are you using ?

Comment: 0.55 version no.